# How to handle hot and cold data efficiently in same table?

Tags: database, postgresql, partitioning

We have a large table of records that are updated a lot during one week then they are frozen and stored as read only for two years. The application is made with hibernate.

Each record have a unique id and a status field that is set to 0 when the record is frozen. IDs are chronologically ordered because they come from a sequence.

We want to store hot records the most efficient way : on SSD drives, with a fillfactor of 45% so updates will be hot updates (index does not change because new tuple is on same page as previous one). Frozen records will be stored on HDD with fillfactor of 100 as they are never modified. Note that there are foreign keys tables. They must also be partitioned the same way so when we detach on partition for main records, we could also detach the corresponding partition of linked items.

We must handle that on database only with no changes on application side (except hibernate mapping).

I attempted several solutions :

**Two level partitioning**

Using range partition on ID and status. One new partition every week split in two sub-partitions for status hot and status cold.

> The primary key must include all partition fields both ID and status. This require to add those fields in all linked items and the application has to be rewritten.

**Using odd/even ID**

I thought of using only odd IDs for new records (which are hot). And add a trigger on status update that increment id so it became even for frozen records. Odd records will be on hot sub-partition, even records on the cold one. For splitting odd and even I thought of using modulus/remainder partitioning.

> This would work fine if the modulus was applied to the raw ID field, unfortunately it is calculated on a hash. So the distribution of record is random. Is there a way to choose the hash function ?

**Using negative ids**

I'm now thinking of using negative IDs for fixed records. Did not tested it yet.

Is there an official way to do that? There are tons of applications that have this kind of behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to expire old rows, don't use a sequence generated `id` to determine what "old" means. Rather, add a timestamp column.

Then partition by range on that timestamp column. Introduce the same timestamp column to all tables that are to have a foreign key relationship to the large table.

Each partition of the large table is list partitioned on status: the partition for 0 is on a tablespace with slow storage, the other partition that contains all other stati is on a tablespace with fast storage. Then rows will automatically move to slow storage when they are frozen.

Don't define foreign keys on the partitioned tables, otherwise you won't be able to drop partitions. Rather, define the foreign key constraints between the individual partitions.

The "fast" subpartition will become empty with age. You might not be able to drop it (if you have foreign keys on the partition level), but you could `VACUUM` the subpartition once it is empty to shrink it.

Then you can expire old data by simply dropping the appropriate partitions.

Comment: Thank you Laurenz. What you describe is what I first tried. But having a unique id and partitioning require that the timestamp is also part of the primary key. So all linked tables must implement two columns reference. How to handle that ?

Comment: My recommendation is to sacrifice the guarantee for global uniqueness of `id`. Instead, define a primary key per partition. If you use identity columns, the sequence will de facto provide global uniqueness anyway.

Comment: I agree with you but I was quite shy to do so. Having you confirm that comfort me. Thank you verymuch, no wonder why you got such reputation ! :)
By the way I think this use case is very common and there should be a way to handle it natively in a simpler way.